# Custom choices list of sonata_type_model field with Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am using Sonata Admin and I have a field of categories and I need to show them in order like a tree in select:

```
<select>
    <option>Category father-1</option>
    <option>--Category child-1-1</option>
    <option>--Category child-1-2</option>
    <option>--Category child-1-3</option>
    <option>----Category child-1-3-1</option>
    <option>----Category child-1-3-2</option>
    <option>--Category child-1-4</option>
    <option>--...</option>
    <option>Category father-2</option>
</select>
```

It's possible? I have tried it including in 'choice_list' an array generate in getTreeCatsArray method:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $tree_cat_array = $this->em->getRepository('MyBundle:Category')->getTreeCatsArray();

    $formMapper
        ->add('category', 'sonata_type_model', array(
                'empty_value' => '', 
                'choice_list' => $tree_cat_array)); 
}
```

This shows the error:

```
The option "choice_list" with value "Array" is expected to be of type "null", "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceListInterface"
```

I am not sure if I must use field type 'sonata_type_model' or 'choice'

Answer (score 29):

OK, I've got the list of categories ordered in tree to include it in the related entity as follows:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $em = $this->modelManager->getEntityManager('MyBundle\Entity\Category');

    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->select('c')
                ->from('MyBundle:Category', 'c')
                ->where('c.parent IS NOT NULL')
                ->orderBy('c.root, c.lft', 'ASC');

    $formMapper
        ...
        ->add('categoria', 'sonata_type_model', array(
            'required' => true, 
            'query' => $query
        ))
        ...
    ; 
}
```

I hope it can help someone

Comment: I had to use `CompanyMyBundle:Category`.

Comment: Hi, have you tried this with required false?
I have and keep getting the cannot set Null value, Excepting Categoria and got null instead, thanks

Comment: Found my solution.
If you want it to be  'required' => false.
setCategory(Category $category = null) so when the form is submitted it doesn't set the value to null and throws an error.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
->add('category', 'entity', array(
        'class'    => 'Acme\Entity\Category',
)
```

This will work only if you have entity `Category`.

See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/418196/Editing-Tree-Structures-in-Symfony2) about creating a tree editor for `Category` entity for *SonataAdminBundle*. [Here](http://habrahabr.ru/post/143413/) is the same article in Russian, but contains missing code in the first variant.

Answer (score 0):

Afterreading the above answers I had to do the following to get the functionality the OP was after:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{

$em = $this->modelManager->getEntityManager('YourBundleFile\YourBundleFileBundle\Entity\YourEntity');

$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb = $qb->add('select', 'u')
        ->add('from', 'YourBundleFile\YourBundleFileBundle\Entity\YourEntity u');

$query = $qb->getQuery();
$arrayType = $query->getArrayResult();

$formMapper
->add('yourProperty', 'choice', array('choices'=>$arrayType))
-end();
}
```